# Email multiple images from a tables path and one report .pdf

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a table (tbl_AccidentImages) that only saves the folder name and image name along with the AccidentID is associated with.

[image: tbl_AccidentImages]

I then use a function to get the path to the images folder using:

```
Public Function GetCurrentPath() As String

'Gets path of current BE table. Move image folder in with BE

Dim strFullPath As String
strFullPath = Mid(DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).TableDefs("tbl_AccidentImages").Connect, 11)
GetCurrentPath = Left(strFullPath, InStrRev(strFullPath, "\"))
End Function
```

Ok, Now the code I'm trying to get work was pieced together because I cant really find anything solid on this. Below is the code and I cant get the attachments to work at all and it stops a:

```
.Attachments.Add (Attachments)
```

and gives the error

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

something went wrong. I dont know maybe there is a easy way to do this and you guys/Gals can show me... Im lost and need assistance! Below is what I have so far.

```
    Public Sub SendOutlookEmail()

Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myOutlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim FilePathToAdd As String
Dim Attachments() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

'Create an Outlook-Instance and a new Mailitem
Set myOutlApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = myOutlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set rs = fDAOGenericRst("SELECT tbl_AccidentImages.ImagePath " & _
                              "FROM tbl_AccidentImages " & _
                              "WHERE (((tbl_AccidentImages.AccidentID)=" & [Forms]![frm_AccidentIllnessEntry]![txtAccidentID] & "));")

    With rs
        If (Not .BOF) And (Not .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            FilePathToAdd = GetCurrentPath() & .Fields("ImagePath")
            .MoveNext
        End If

        If (Not .BOF) And (Not .EOF) Then
            Do Until .EOF
 'Adds a ; between each path and takes away \ between the file path and the file
                FilePathToAdd = FilePathToAdd & "; " & Replace(GetCurrentPath() & .Fields("ImagePath"), "\\", "\")
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        .Close

    End With

    If FilePathToAdd <> "" Then
        Attachments = Split(FilePathToAdd, ";")
        For i = LBound(Attachments) To UBound(Attachments)
            If Attachments(i) <> "" Then
                myMail.Attachments.Add Trim(Attachments(i))
            End If
            Next i
        End If

    With myMail
    .To = "recipient@somewhere.com"
    .Subject = "Subject Line"
    .Body = "This is the body"
    .Attachments.Add (Attachments)

'Send or Display email
        .Display
       '.Send
    End With

'Terminate the Outlook Application instance
    myOutlApp.Quit

'Destroy the object variables and free the memory
    Set myMail = Nothing
    Set myOutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You already added attachments in the array loop. Remove this secondary .Add line. Instead of bothering with filling and looping array, why don't you add attachments in recordset loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already added attachments in array loop. Remove this secondary Add line. Don't bother with array, just add attachments in recordset loop.

```
    With rs
        If (Not .BOF) And (Not .EOF) Then
            Do Until .EOF
                'takes away \ between the file path and the file
                MyMail.Attachments.Add Replace(GetCurrentPath() & .Fields("ImagePath"), "\\", "\")
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With

    With myMail
    .To = "recipient@somewhere.com"
    .Subject = "Subject Line"
    .Body = "This is the body"
    .Display
    End With
```

Comment: June7, your solution works great! I have a question though. I needed to attach a report "rpt_AccidentIllnessEntry". I only know how to attach using DoCmd.SendObject acReport. How can i attach it as well?

Comment: You would have to first save report as a PDF then include that PDF in email Attachments. DoCmd.OutputTo can save as PDF. Please mark one answer as accepted if it resolved issue. Upvote as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to add the attachments twice - once should be enough, hence the code may become:

```
If FilePathToAdd <> "" Then
    With myMail
        .To = "recipient@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Subject Line"
        .Body = "This is the body"
        With .Attachments
            Dim att
            For each att in Split(FilePathToAdd, ";")
                If att <> "" Then .Add Trim(att)
            Next att
        End With
        .Send
    End With
End If
```